# LastExitCode of invoke-command does not match condition

Tags: powershell, jenkins, invoke-command

I am running script through jenkins and the Invoke command should fail as the file already exits and should reach exit code 1 and error out and show a fail in jenkins but instead it still is exiting 0 as green

I have tried using Try catch and using $? but still cannot get this to show as red when failure

```
$Time = $args[1]
$Server = $args[2]
$username = $args[3]
$password = $args[4]

$pass="$password"|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("ad\$username",$pass)

$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Server -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction Stop

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {netsh trace start capture=yes tracefile=C:\Traces\netsh.etl}
If ($LastExitCode -eq 1)
{
exit 1
}

write-host "hello world"
start-sleep -Seconds $Time
Invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {netsh trace stop}
If ($LastExitCode -eq 1)
{
exit 1
}


exit 0
```

The file already exists which should be expected but not reaching the exit 1 inside either if statements when it should.

Comment: The `$LastExistCode` you are testing is on the local system, but you are running the command on a remote system.  Try returning the `$LastExistCode` at the end of your scriptblock and test the result of the `Invoke-Command` call.

Comment: @boxdog, your answer is correct - post it as an answer instead of comment, so that it can be approved by the OP.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to return this? Thanks

Comment: @Joost Posted as requested.

Answer (score 2):

The `$LastExistCode` you are testing is on the *local* system, but you are running the command on a *remote* system. Try returning the `$LastExistCode` at the end of your scriptblock and test the result of the `Invoke-Command`

For example:

```
$result = Invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {netsh trace stop; $LastExitCode}
If ($result -eq 1)
{
    exit 1
}
```

This assumes that `netsh` itself doesn't return anything (I didn't test it).  If it does, you can typically supress the output by piping it to `Out-Null`:

```
Invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {netsh trace stop | Out-Null; $LastExitCode}
```